# Datepicker WPFToolkit: shows truncated month

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have a problem with the datepicker. 
When I click on the datepicker, the month is truncated, how is displayed in the image.

[Image of my problem](http://1drv.ms/1EKZec1)

```
<toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="datePickerDataToFatturaSATA" Height="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></toolkit:DatePicker>
```

Here is the actual Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Da" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
    <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="datePickerDataFromFattura" Height="25" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></toolkit:DatePicker>
    <Label Content="A" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
    <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="datePickerDataToFattura" Height="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></toolkit:DatePicker>
    <Button x:Name="InviaFattura" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="150" Content="Invia Fattura" Style="{DynamicResource RedButtonStyle}" Click="InviaFattura_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Help please!

Comment: Can you provide all your grid ?

Comment: Hi cedric, I add all grid in the previews msg